# Difference between cold-hearted and hard-hearted

Tags: word-difference

According to Google, **cold-hearted** is "*lacking affection or warmth*" while **hard-hearted** is "*incapable of being moved to pity or tenderness*" but I'm unable to differentiate between these meanings. Also, both have "unfeeling" as a synonym.

Can someone explain the subtle difference between the usage these words?

Comment: Both means the same. GoogleNgram shows that "hard-hearted" is used more. But I have heard "cold-hearted" more. :)

Comment: @Usernew - that may just mean that you personally are more "cold-hearted" than "hard-hearted". (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle You heard it right :) I am 'Cold-hearted" X2 + "heard-hearted". Now we are going off-topic :P

Comment: @Usernew - Now, we are illustrating the meaning of "[lighthearted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lighthearted)". (0:

Comment: The two meanings given in the post are correct and they *are* different. They just have some overlap in meaning. A cold-hearted killer may torture his victims to death for days without any feeling for them, and a parent may harden their heart against the plaintive cries of their children to deviate from a certain plan.

Answer (score 2):

Cold-hearted carries more of a connotation of being unfeeling and lacking in empathy - the ability to share, understand and feel another person's feelings -  whereas hard-hearted carries more of a connotation of lacking in sympathy - an understanding of and feeling for the sadness or suffering of others.

Cold-hearted is more of a passive condition, of being *un*interested in the feelings of others. Hard-hearted can be more of an active condition, of being *dis*interested in the suffering of others.

And there is a very large overlap of synonimity between them.